How to get Bootcamp Windows 10 installation to boot after removing macOS?
The macOS installation on my ageing 2013-model MacBook Pro (MacBookPro10,2, "Early 2013") was becoming unusable, so I went on to replace it with Ubuntu. This worked as a charm, but after this I am unable to boot into the Windows installation on the separate partition. It was initially installed using Bootcamp, and was booting fine before I started. It was originally installed as Windows 7, later upgraded to Windows 8, 8.1 and 10.
I started out with a partition table looking like this (as seen from Linux):

/dev/sda1 - EFI system partition
/dev/sda2 - APFS macOS
/dev/sda4 - BOOTCAMP (Windows)

I booted into the Ubuntu installer, and had it reformat /dev/sda2 as ext4 and mount as root. It discovered /dev/sda1, mounting it at /boot/efi. I also mount /dev/sda4 as /mnt/c without any problems (and all files are there).
Grub does not see the Windows partition (os-prober ignores EFI OSes, apparently) and pressing Alt during boot didn't show Windows any longer, so I installed rEFInd. It gave me a "Boot Windows (Legacy) from BOOTCAMP" option that boots into the Windows blue "Recovery" screen:
Your PC/Device needs to be repaired
The application or operating system couldn't be loaded because a required file is missing or contains errors.
File: \Windows\system32\winload.exe
Error code: 0xc000000e

From Ubuntu, I can see the winload.exe (and winload.efi) files there just fine.
Following the procedure set out in this guide, I used gdisk to update the protective MBR, making sure all three GPT partitions are also visible from the MBR.
Booting the Windows 10 USB and trying to run Startup Repair fails (with an empty log). Using the instructions from "How to fix the Windows 10 boot loader from Windows" I was able to create EFI boot files (bcdboot C:\windows /s D: /f UEFI). Booting into rEFInd, I can select the Windows bootloaded that I have now added. This fails with this message:
rEFInd - Booting OS
Starting bootmgfw.efi
Using load options ''
BlInitializeLibrary failed 0xc00000bb

Is the bootcamp installation of Windows special in some way, and have I screwed it up completely by removing the macOS partitions?
EDIT: As requested, here is what gdisk reports for disk partitions:
Disk /dev/sda: 490234752 sectors, 233.8 GiB
Model: APPLE SSD SM256E
Sector size (logical/physical): 512/4096 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 00001F0C-758C-0000-B55E-0000EB650000
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 33
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 490234718
Partitions will be aligned on 8-sector boundaries
Total free space is 1533 sectors (766.5 KiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1              40          409639   200.0 MiB   EF00  EFI system partition
   2          409640       338300263   161.1 GiB   AF0A  Customer
   4       338300928       490233855   72.4 GiB    EF00  BOOTCAMP

Here is how the protective MBR is set up:
Disk size is 490234752 sectors (233.8 GiB)
MBR disk identifier: 0xBC0E843F
MBR partitions:

Number  Boot  Start Sector   End Sector   Status      Code
   1                     1           39   primary     0xEE
   2                    40       409639   primary     0xEF
   3                409640    338300263   primary     0x83
   4      *      338300928    490233855   primary     0x07

This is fairly close to how Apple BootCamp set up the partitions before I started, it also made all partitions visible in the MBR table.
The APFS partition (which now is formatted as ext4) did contain several sub-partitions, but I assumed I did not need any of those, but maybe the Apple bootloader used something in the EFI boot sequence?
EDIT: After messing around with the partitioning and bcdboot, os-prober adds an entry to run bootmgfw.efi. This does not boot (blank screen). Same result when trying to run that entry from rEFInd. I also tried to add a "chainloader +1" entry, but that is not supported from EFI Grub. In rEFInd if I select "Boot legacy whole disk application", or if I select "Windows" from the Apple Alt-bootmenu, I get the winload.exe error mentioned above.

Bootcamp is MacOS software, a virtualizartion solution of sorts. It needs the OS to run.

Bootcamp isn’t a hypervisor.

@ChanganAuto: You are absolutely wrong. The Boot Camp Assistant is an macOS application that simplifies the process of installing Windows on a Mac. Virtualization is not used and the resultant Windows installation is not dependent on macOS.

nafmo: There is something wrong with your question. If you properly used gdisk to hybrid partition your internal drive, then it would not be possible to properly recreate the Windows boot files for a UEFI boot by using the bcdboot command. Perhaps you could use gdisk to printout and post the MBR and GUID partition tables.

@DavidAnderson: I did use gdisk to create a protective MBR, and after that run bcdboot. I was booting the Windows installer from a Ventoy image, that might have complicated things? I'll try to post the details when I get some time to try recovering the machine. I have most likely missed a couple of steps of what I did in my summary above. First time I accidentally targeted Ventoy's EFI partition...
I wonder how the Mac normally boots Windows on bootcamp as the MIcrosoft bootloader wasn't originally on the EFI partition.

If you originally used the Boot Camp Assistant to install Windows 10, then the type of booting (BIOS versus UEFI) depends on whether you have an Early or Late 2013 MacBook Pro. Do you know whether you have an Early or Late model?  Apple has a website to help determine this. If you upgraded to Windows 10 from a previous version of Windows, then you should include this information in your question.

Thank you, I have updated the question. It's a MacBookPro10,2, which is "early 2013". I initially installed Windows 7, and upgraded it (through 8 and 8.1, I believe).

I'm very tempted trying to just reinstall Windows on the machine (backing up the few files I want to keep; I can read the NTFS partition just fine from Linux). The main issue I had with that is that I'm not sure which media and product key I started with, but AFAICT Windows has online activation and should "just work" if I do that. I hope.

If you reinstall, you should not need an activation key. You can also login at https://login.live.com/ to see if your computer is listed under your account. For example, this is what is listed for the Mac I am using. Since I already had Windows 10 installed, I was able to do a clean install of Windows 11 for free. Note that I was able to install Windows 11 on my Mac even though the WDDM driver was not version 2.0 or higher. The same most likely will be true for your Mac.

It's not listed there, but that's because I have refuse to connect the machine to an online account. Looks like i will have to go the reinstall route. I'll post back here when I have had time to try that.

If you reinstall, do you have the drivers (Windows Support Software)? Are you going to try to reinstall to BIOS or UEFI boot?

Since you upgraded from Windows 7, your Mac should have a BIOS booting Windows 10. Below are some errors I found in your current configuration. Post a comment if you do not understand how to fix any of these errors.
Partitioning Errors
The output from gdisk should appear as shown below.
For the GUID Partition Table (GPT):
Disk /dev/sda: 490234752 sectors, 233.8 GiB
Model: APPLE SSD SM256E
Sector size (logical/physical): 512/4096 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 00001F0C-758C-0000-B55E-0000EB650000
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 33
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 490234718
Partitions will be aligned on 8-sector boundaries
Total free space is 1533 sectors (766.5 KiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1              40          409639   200.0 MiB   EF00  EFI system partition
   2          409640       338300263   161.1 GiB   8300  Customer
   3       338300928       490233855   72.4 GiB    0700  BOOTCAMP

I believe the above differs from you output in the following ways.

My entries are sorted.
The codes for the Linux and Windows partition are different.

For the MBR Partition Table:
Disk size is 490234752 sectors (233.8 GiB)
MBR disk identifier: 0xBC0E843F
MBR partitions:

Number  Boot  Start Sector   End Sector   Status      Code
   1                     1       409639   primary     0xEE
   2                409640    338300263   primary     0x83
   3      *      338300928    490233855   primary     0x07

I believe the above differs from you output in the following ways.

The first partition should cover EFI partition given in the GPT.
Since the EFI partition should not exist in the MBR, the Linux and Windows partitions are numbered differently.

Linux Boot Files
An Ubuntu installation should be bootable from the Mac Startup Manager. This is where you hold down the option at startup until the icons appear. From Ubuntu, the following files should appear in the EFI partition. The files below are from an installation of Ubuntu 24.04 LTS Desktop.
$ ls -l /boot/efi/EFI/BOOT
total 1868
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 966664 Jun  3 10:43 BOOTX64.EFI
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  88344 Jun  3 10:43 fbx64.efi
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 856280 Jun  3 10:43 mmx64.efi
$ ls -l /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/
total 4376
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     108 Jun  3 10:43 BOOTX64.CSV
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     126 Jun  3 10:43 grub.cfg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2656136 Jun  3 10:43 grubx64.efi
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  856280 Jun  3 10:43 mmx64.efi
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  966664 Jun  3 10:43 shimx64.efi

Note: The contents of the BOOTX64.EFI file is the same as the contents of the shimx64.efi file and both mmx64.efi files are the same.
Your installation of the UEFI boot files for Windows should have created and added files to the following folders.
/boot/efi/EFI/Boot
/boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft

A single file named bootx64.efi should have been written to /boot/efi/EFI/Boot folder, which overwrites any existing BOOTX64.EFI file placed there by a previous Ubuntu installation. This file can be replaced by the contents of /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi file. The /boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft folder can be removed.
Windows Booting Errors
You installed the Windows boot files for UEFI booting. This is incorrect. You should have installed for BIOS booting. To install, you will first have to boot from a Windows 10 installation USB drive. Open a Command Prompt window and enter the following commands.
bcdboot c:\windows /s c: /f bios
bootsect /nt60 c: /mbr

You should now be able to BIOS boot Windows from the Mac Startup Manager. This is where you hold down the option at startup until the icons appear.

Booting the recovery media from USB and running bcdboot and bootsect saved the day! I can now boot into Windows (using the Mac ⌥ boot menu) and from rEFInd. Using efibootmgr, I have set rEFInd as the primary menu, allowing me to easily chose between booting into Ubuntu or Windows.
Thank you so much for your patience!
